# How to update an item in a list that is value to a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So its something like this:

```
{'golden': [1], 
'crazy': [1]}
```

and then probably update it to

```
{'golden': [2], 
'crazy': [2]}
```

I just want to know how I can access that list in the value of the dictionary and then change it from 1 to 2.

Comment: do you want `your_dict['golden'][0] = 2` ?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(d, [2])`

Answer (score 1):

You can access dict items even if they are lists the same way, so

`dict['golden']`

returns that array. If you want to set the first item in the array to 0, you would do it the same way you would normally update list values:
  `dict['golden'][0] = 2`

Or append simpmly by doing 
`dict['golden'].append(2)`

If you never add to that list though, it doesn't make sense for your dict to be list objects, it might as well just be an integer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
your_dict['golden'][0] += 1
your_dict['crazy'][0] += 1
```